# Handling an exception, and only executing code if an exception was not thrown

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

My `script_a.php`:

```
try {
    Class1::tryThis();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Do stuff here to show the user an error occurred
}
```

`Class1::tryThis()` has something like:

```
public function tryThis() {
    Class2::tryThat();
    self::logSuccessfulEvent();
}
```

The problem is that `Class2::tryThat()` can throw an exception.

If it does throw an exception, it seems that the line `self::logSuccessfulEvent();` still gets executed.

How can I refactor this code so that `self::logSuccessfulEvent()` only occurs when an exception is not thrown, yet at the same time letting `script_a.php` know when an exception *has* been thrown?

Comment: the problem is somewhere else

Comment: "it seems that"? If `tryThat` throws an unhandled exception, the next line in `tryThis` (`self::logSuccessfulEvent()`) **will not be run.**

Comment: @webbiedave and OP: You are absolutely correct. The next line could not run, and it was being executed beforehand where I did not realize. Thus, PHP exceptions work as I expected: no code is executed after the statement that throws the exception in the current block of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function will return whether or not the operation was successful (true = success, false = failure)

```
public function tryThis() {
   $success = true;

   try {
       Class2::tryThat();
       self::logSuccessfulEvent();
   } catch( Exception $e) {
       $success = false;
   }

   return $success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing does not seem to be the case.

Code:

```
<?php
class Class1 {
    public function tryThis() {
        echo "Class1::tryThis() was called.\n";
        Class2::tryThat();
        self::logSuccessfulEvent();
    }

    public function logSuccessfulEvent() {
        echo "Class1::logSuccessfulEvent() was called.\n";
    }
}

class Class2 {
    public function tryThat() {
        echo "Class2::tryThat() was called.\n";
        throw new Exception('Exception generated in Class2::tryThat()');
    }
}

try {
    Class1::tryThis();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Class1::tryThis() was called.
Class2::tryThat() was called.
Exception generated in Class2::tryThat()
```

As you can see, the `Class1::logSuccessfulEvent()` method is never executed when an exception is generated in `Class2::tryThat()`, and it shouldn't (won't) either.  Exceptions bubble up until they are caught or produce a fatal error.  Once an exception is caught, control of the program returns to the code after the `catch` block.  In this particular case, that would mean that control of the program never reaches the logging method.

Comment: That's how I assumed exceptions would work. Perhaps it's a sign that my code is calling a method before the exception being raised.